# group + count with different column types

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a customer model which represents customers and their SINGLE purchase at the shop at a certain date.

For example, if Customer1 came in at 1/1 and bought an Basketball.
While Customer2 came at 2/1 and bought a Doll, the model will look like this:

```
|----------------|------------|------------------|------------|
|    Customer    |    Date    |       Item       |    Name    |
|----------------|------------|------------------|-------------
|       1        |    1/1     |    Basketball    |     Bu     |
|----------------|------------|------------------|-------------
|       2        |    2/1     |       Doll       |     Hu     |
|----------------|------------|------------------|-------------
```

Now, If I wished to fetch a table the who is grouped by date, that sums up all of the bought items at a certain day, I will write something like this:

```
customers.group("DATE_FORMAT(date(started_at), '%d-%m')").count
```

That will give me back a table which looks like this:

```
|------------|-------------|
|    Date    |    Count    |
|------------|-------------|
|    1/1     |      1      |
|------------|-------------|
|    2/1     |      1      |
|------------|-------------|
```

But what If I would like to have a count of each item at each single day, PLUS the sum of all items in the shop? How would I write it in rails for getting the following output?

```
|------------|------------------|------------|-----------|
|    Date    |    Basketball    |    Doll    |    Sum    |
|------------|------------------|------------|-----------|
|    1/1     |        1         |      0     |     1     |
|------------|------------------|------------|-----------|
|    2/1     |        0         |      1     |     1     |
|------------|------------------|------------|-----------|
```

- It's alright to indicate in the query itself the item names I would like to sum-up. in this case. it's just 'Basketball' and 'Doll'.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Item = 'Basketball' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS BasketBall,
       SUM( CASE WHEN Item = 'Doll' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Doll,
       COUNT(1) AS Totalsum 
  FROM Customers
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: You could possibly simplify the last column in your query by just using `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: looks awesome! but in rails?

Comment: the answer is very useful and so I voted her up. Yet, it didn't solved my question, as I couldn't translate that to rails :)